Fluentd send logs to http
I have a fluentd setup that adds all logs into a new json object called log. I would like to post to http match that only the elements within the log object.
How can I do it?
Below my configuration:
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/containers/*.log, /var/log/pods/*.log
  exclude_path ["/var/log/containers/fluentd-*.log", "/var/log/containers/argocd-*.log", "/var/log/containers/cilium-*.log", "/var/log/containers/csi-*.log", "/var/log/containers/cpc-*.log", "/var/log/containers/hubble-*.log", "/var/log/containers/kube-*.log", "/var/log/containers/cert-manager-*.log", "/var/log/containers/core-dns-*.log", "/var/log/containers/ingress-*.log"]
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  tag container_logs
  format /(?<log>\{[^{}]*"message"\s*:\s*"(?<message>[^"]*)"[^{}]*"level"\s*:\s*"(?<level>[^"]*)"[^{}]*"traceId"\s*:\s*"(?<traceId>[^"]*)"[^{}]*"namespace"\s*:\s*"(?<namespace>[^"]*)"[^{}]*"requestId"\s*:\s*"(?<requestId>[^"]*)"[^{}]*"service"\s*:\s*"(?<service>[^"]*)"[^{}]*\})/
</source>
<match>
  @type http
  endpoint https://events.baselime.io/v1/logs
  headers {"x-api-key":"xxx", "baselime-data-source": "fluentd/k8s"}
  open_timeout 2
  json_array true
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
</match>

I tried different approaches like filters, another matches but unfortunately I can't configure it correctly. Could anyone clarify an idea for me?

Can you add the filters you have tried? Also elaborate more by giving an example events and what events should be matched.
